# Failed to get RPC descriptor

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have the following proto files:

service_myservice.proto

```
service MyService {
    rpc GetData(GetRequest) returns (GetResponse) {}
}
```

server.go

```
type Server struct {
    pb.UnimplementedMyServiceServer
    config util.Config
}

// NewServer creates a new gRPC server.
func NewServer(config util.Config) (*Server, error) {
    server := &Server{
        config: config,
    }

    return server, nil
}
```

and then in main package I am calling this function

```
func runGrpcServer(config util.Config) {
    server, err := gapi.NewServer(config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal().Err(err).Msg("cannot create server")
    }

    grpcLogger := grpc.UnaryInterceptor(gapi.GrpcLogger)
    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer(grpcLogger)
    pb.RegisterMyServiceServer(grpcServer, server)
    reflection.Register(grpcServer)

    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", config.GRPCServerAddress)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal().Err(err).Msg("cannot create listener")
    }

    log.Info().Msgf("start gRPC server at %s", listener.Addr().String())
    err = grpcServer.Serve(listener)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal().Err(err).Msg("cannot start gRPC server")
    }
}
```

I am using evans (https://github.com/ktr0731/evans) to test my grpc calls.
My gRPC server is running and I can connect to the localhost on the specific port (9090) with evans.

However, when I call `show service` in evans I get following response:

```
localhost:9090> show service
+---------+-----+--------------+---------------+
| SERVICE | RPC | REQUEST TYPE | RESPONSE TYPE |
+---------+-----+--------------+---------------+
+---------+-----+--------------+---------------+
localhost:9090> call GetData
command call: failed to get the RPC descriptor for: GetData: service unselected
```

I thought that if I add `pb.UnimplementedMyServiceServer` in my `Server` struct, that this is forward compatible. But apparently, I am missing some piece of code.

What part is missing, for the `MyService` to be forward compatible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When **evans** is used in the **REPL** mode, you should select a package before calling `show service` and select a service before calling `call GetData`.

```
localhost:9090> show package
+-------------------------+
|         PACKAGE         |
+-------------------------+
| example                 |
| grpc.reflection.v1      |
| grpc.reflection.v1alpha |
+-------------------------+

localhost:9090> package example

example@localhost:9090> show service
+-----------+---------+--------------+---------------+
|  SERVICE  |   RPC   | REQUEST TYPE | RESPONSE TYPE |
+-----------+---------+--------------+---------------+
| MyService | GetData | GetRequest   | GetResponse   |
+-----------+---------+--------------+---------------+

example@localhost:9090> service MyService

example.MyService@localhost:9090> call GetData
id (TYPE_INT32) => 1
```